# WPA Password not remembered after a reboot

Tags: windows, security, wireless-networking, passwords

Every-time I reboot my laptop with WinXP, I have to re-enter my wireless password. I've looked but found no place to check to tell it to remember it. This worked at one time but I'm not sure what changed. Any Ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [here](http://compnetworking.about.com/od/windowsxpnetworking/a/automaticwifixp.htm):

> To enable automatic configuration, ensure the "Use Windows to configure my wireless network settings" checkbox is checked on the Wireless Networks tab of the Wireless Network Connection properties window. Automatic wireless Internet / Wi-Fi network configuration will be disabled if this checkbox is unchecked. You must be logged on with Windows XP administrative privileges to enable / disable this feature.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Windows XP has a bug where it is haunted by old wifi keys. The only solution I've found that really works:

1. Control Panel -> Network Connection
2. Right click on wireless network connection
3. select properties
4. **delete all** the preferred networks (you will **lose all your wifi keys** unfortunately)

   [image: delete preferred networks]
5. reboot
6. **remove all the wireless keys from the registry** by deleting all the Interface Guid subkeys from (notice that there might be more Interface Guids here than you expect. My theory is that you can have multiple old keys here that cause the old wireless key to come back)

   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WZCSVC\Parameters\Interfaces*

   [image]

   You can also use [WirelessKeyView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/wireless_key.html) to view and delete these keys sometimes, but I have found ones that could only be deleted via the registry.
7. reboot
8. scan the networks
9. add the network again and it should now correctly remember the password